# amCharts5: rotated x axis labels are overflowing out of view (javascript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amcharts, amcharts5

I'm rotating my x axis labels by -30, however, the last few  labels are been hidden and not showing (see picture below). please let me know what I can do to fix this.

code is available in the following gist: https://gist.github.com/chawkichalladia/3b0636316d1674ad31652cfc2f50682a

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to adding some padding to the right of the chart and the library does not allow for content outside of the chart container.

`chart.set('paddingRight', 200);`